# Can an attribute of an entity have a relationship with another entity

Tags: database, entity-relationship

My scenario is that *drivers* are defined as an *attribute* of the *employees* (entity). Is it possible that *driver* can have a relationship with another entity, for example a *vehicle*?

Answer (score 0):

well i guess you can relate only the drivers from the employees i would sugest you to make a superclass called employee and split it  with non drivers and drivers or as needed and  then relate the drivers with the vehicles hope it's usefull and sorry for bad English

Comment: Is there any other way of obtaining it in a ER model.

Comment: no you can´t relate atributes in the ER model but if you only have 2 types you can split them as i said if you want to relate all you can relate the superclass employee or if you want to relate the drivers you can place it directly to the subclass

Answer (score 0):

The ER model doesn't allow attributes to be related.  Attributes are seen as mappings to value sets, i.e. they're edges to leaf nodes.  Chen defined a shift operator in his 2nd paper which allows value sets to be converted to entity sets, or vice versa, but that wouldn't help you here, since what you need is a driver entity set that is a subtype of the employee entity set, not one consisting of yes/no or whatever the codomain of your current driver attribute is.